# I cannot setVisibility and specific layout from onCreate() in android but in onClick you can do it?

Tags: android, android-layout

When I get a layout from xml and use `setVisibility(INVISIBLE)` I cannot write that in the `onCreate()` method but inside action Listener like `onclick` you can write the code `setVisibility` and hide the layout, how come I cannot write and set `visibility` of that layout in `onCreate`?

Comment: you can do that. show your code are you trying??

Comment: you must use `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

Comment: Are you trying to do that before of after `setContent`

Comment: You can use it after setContentView

Comment: definitely you can do that. What if you are making view dynamically i.e not using XML ?

Answer (score 5):

You don't have View's view object inside the `onCreate()` obviously you should specify it like `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Where as in `onClick(View v)` it already passes the **View's view object** so no need to specify there. simply you can use that.

I hope it would help you

Answer (score 2):

Use `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` .

Answer (score 1):

After `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`, find the `View` on which you want to call `setVisiblity()`.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Output);
    Output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set Layout visibility in android to (visible/invisible/gone) by the XML code like: `android:visiblity = "invisible"`
  Or you can use the Attributes list, example:[screenshot of "Option" in Attributes list to set the visibility of a layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy3WC.png)